# Append custom style to a GWT CellTable (in this case all cells)

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have a case where I want to append

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to the style of each cell in my CellTable. Currently it applies to all tables, but it would be nice to know both have to apply it for a specific CellTable, and all CellTables.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

CellTables have their own [CssResource](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.Style.html). To override this style applied to all cells in a cellTable, create a new css file :

```
/* Incremental changes from CellTable.css */ 
.cellTableCell {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then create your own CellTable.Resources interface :

```
public interface TableResources extends CellTable.Resources {

    /**
       * The styles applied to the table.
       */
    interface TableStyle extends CellTable.Style {
    }

    @Override
    @Source({ CellTable.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "MyOwnCellTableStyleSheet.css" })
    TableStyle cellTableStyle();

}
```

Finally, when creating your cellTable, use the [constructor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#CellTable%28int,%20com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable.Resources%29) that lets you specify which Resources to use

```
CellTable<Object> myCellTable = new CellTable<Object>(15, GWT.create(TableResources.class));
```

For a working example, look at the Expenses sample provided in the GWT SDK.

Comment: Very nice answer, worked well with me, except that on GWT 2.4 you have to cast to Resources like (Resources)GWT.create(TableResources.class) to work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I found out that it also works without the TableStyle interface altogether. You can just write:    CellTable.Style cellTableStyle(); This reduces the boilerplate somewhat. I tried it on GWT 2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this the easy way:

```
CellTable<YourObj> yourTable = new CellTable<YourObj>();
yourTable.getElement().getStyle().setWhiteSpace(WhiteSpace.NOWRAP);
```

No css files, no weird boilerplate code.