# How do I completely disable row selection in a CellTable?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to completely view updates when a row is selected in a CellTable. How can this be done? In the following test case, using [NoSelectionModel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/NoSelectionModel.html), the view is still updated: clicking on a row changes the background and border colors of the row until another row is clicked.

```
    CellTable<String> table = new CellTable<String>();

    TextColumn<String> column = new TextColumn<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String string)
        {
            return string;
        }
    };

    table.addColumn(column);

    List<String> sampleData = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");

    table.setRowData(sampleData);

    final NoSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new NoSelectionModel<String>();
    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

    RootPanel.get().add(table);
```

I've also attempted to subclass SingleSelectionModel with empty override methods, without success.

I can fake the behavior I want by providing empty [CSS stylings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386070/append-custom-style-to-a-gwt-celltable-in-this-case-all-cells) for selected rows, but that method seems hack-ish.

Comment: What you're seeing is the keyboard-selection highlighting (really useful when you're not using the mouse to interact with the table), maybe you can try tweaking the keyboard selection policy?

Comment: Awesome, setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED) does the trick. Care to write that in an answer so I can flag this question as answered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're seeing is the keyboard-selection highlighting (really useful when you're not using the mouse to interact with the table).
You can disable it using [`setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/HasKeyboardSelectionPolicy.html#setKeyboardSelectionPolicy%28com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasKeyboardSelectionPolicy.KeyboardSelectionPolicy%29)

Comment: perfect! been looking for this for ages! thanks alot! :)