# GWT cell rendering based on selection state

Tags: gwt

I've a custom image cell in a CellTree. I want to render two different images depending on the row/node selection state, for example if the row/node is selected I want to render image A if not selected image B. The images couple is different for each node.

What is the best way to get the selection state in the render method of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

#### CSS solution

If you can work with background images here, the easiest and most efficient solution would be CSS based.

Take a look at /com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.css (in gwt-user.jar). There you see the css classes ".cellTreeItem" and ".cellTreeSelectedItem". The latter one already has an image. You could assign it your own, and for ".cellTreeItem" a different one.

For general information how to adjust CellTable/CellTree/... styles, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387210/291741

#### Cell solution

You could construct your cell with the SelectionModel like

```java
public MyCell(SelectionModel selectionModel) {
  this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
}

public void render(final Cell.Context context, final Node value,
    final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

  if (selectionModel.isSelected(...
}
```

However, you will probably need to retrigger the cell rendering when the selection changes. It's probably possible, but I've never done that.

Comment: Unfortunately the CSS solution is not possible because images couples are different for each node. I will update the question with the constraint.

Comment: Nice the selection model solution.