# Append custom style to a widget extending GWT CellTable

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I implemented my own widget by extending GWT CellTable. I am now looking to remove the 2px table borders that GWT has by default on the table. Here is the structure of my custom widget:

> public class CustomWidget extends CellTable {
>
> public CustomWidget (DataModel _dataModel, Updater _updater) { ... } }

I saw a related answer [here on StackOveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386070/append-custom-style-to-a-gwt-celltable-in-this-case-all-cells) and followed those steps. However, I extend CellTable to create my own widget, which is different from the original post where an instance of a basic CellTable is created. The step I need help with is how to tweak the following line of code, given in the other post, to provide a new Resources class to my custom CellTable widget:

> CellTable myCellTable = new CellTable(15,
> GWT.create(TableResources.class));

where TableResources extends CellTable.Resources.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to define a css class (somewhere you make sure that it loads in your target page):

```
.myBorderlessCell
{
    border: 0;
}
```

and then in your java code:

```
CustomWidget cw = new CustomWidget(...);
cw.addStyleName("myBorderlessCell");
```

this overrides border attribute of your widget.